# AppCompatTextView autoSizeTextType not working

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-appcompat, android-textview-autosize

In my `activity.xml`, I have two `AppCompatTextView` that looks like this:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/user_full_name_text_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="@string/full_name"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/user_name_text_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="@string/username"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/user_view"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/user_full_name_text_view"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_full_name_text_view"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

In my design tab, this part of the activity looks like this:

[image: Android Design Tab]

Now that looks correct as the text has correctly auto sized to fill the height of the first `AppCompatTextView`. However, when I run my app on mobile, it looks like this:

[image: Android Mobile Design]

Why is the text not auto sizing? How do I fix this so that way the text fills the entire width and height of the `AppCompatTextView`?

Answer (score 3):

Auto sizing [doesn't play well with `wrap_content`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview#setting-textview-autosize), probably because it needs to know its size before it can say how big its content will be. Do you have any of that going on anywhere in the hierarchy, like in the layout your `AppCompatTextViews` are in?

Right now your widths depend on how wide `parent` is, but if that's `wrap_content` (or *its* parent is, etc etc) then eventually that text view is gonna get asked how wide it wants to be, and it gets confused

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that adding `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` is not enough.
When you are using `uniform` type, you should specify step granularity as well.
Try to use such attributes below:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    ...
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="24sp"
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
    ... />
```

Comment: Instead of setting granularity, give maxlines as 1.